# What payment processors work with WordPress Caldera and CiviCRM, and which of those work with recurring

Tags: wordpress, payment-processor, recurring-contributions, caldera-forms

This is an open-ended question to pull together information as folk develop more options. The below answer is based on snips from https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/pl/4refrsqotib9tf9gyrscffk8my

Answer (score 2):

In response to a question about WP, Caldera and iATS play nicely and do recurring

danaskallman said:

> no, it's either of these two add-ons  as of now stripe and authorize. iATS isn't an option for payment processors so it would need to be developed likely.

Andrei said:

> the official CF payment add-ons support PayPal Express and Pro, Authorize.net, Dwolla, Stripe, Braintree, and PayFast gateways.
>
> As @danaskallman mentioned CFC integrates with Stripe and Authorize, with integrates I mean that it calculates/updates the payment fees and transaction ids, etc.
>
> And recurring contributions are not currently integrated/supported.

agileware_justin said:

> we developed a Caldera payment processor for eWAY Rapid API (eWAY payment gateway) - this hasn't been published OSS yet.
>
> Can confirm, Caldera CiviCRM is missing recurring contribution feature.

Comment: What is the "official CF payment add-ons" talked about? Is it an extension? I'm looking for an extension that works with PayFast

Comment: Possibly this (found by googling "caldera form payments") https://calderaforms.com/payments/

Answer (score 2):

Just an update on this question, Agileware have developed the following for Caldera Forms:

- EWAY payment gateway integration for Caldera Forms using EWAY Rapid 3.0 API
- CiviCRM recurring payments for memberships and donations using Caldera Forms
- Ability to view and update stored credit cards using Caldera Forms

This work will / is and be publicised in a series of blog posts on https://civicrm.org/news and https://blog.agileware.com.au

You can contact us directly if you are interested in these features at https://agileware.com.au/contact

Comment: awesome aussies strike again